# Formatar data dd/mm/yyyy em um DataTable.net jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-datatables

Como eu formato essa data 2016-10-23T20:30:01.017 em um [Datatable.net](https://datatables.net/) no formato brasileiro dd/mm/aaaa ?

**Controller:**

Esse trecho relevante do código é onde eu populo o objeto que está no formato ok: dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss:

```
List<Cliente> lTotalClienteAux = _IRepositorio.ListarCliente().ToList();

                List<Cliente> lTotalCliente = new List<Cliente>();
                foreach (var item in lTotalClienteAux)
                {
                    Cliente oCliente = new Cliente();
                    oCliente.ClienteID = item.ClienteID;
                    oCliente.DataCadastro = item.DataCadastro;                       
                    lTotalCliente.Add(oCliente);
                }
```

**View**
Quando carrega aqui na View o formato muda para: 2016-10-24T20:35:13.617

```
{
      "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
      var dt = full['DataCadastro'];
      return '<td>' + dt + '</td>';
     }
},
```

**web.config**
No web.config tenho essa tag indicando a cultura:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="pt-BR" culture="pt-BR" enableClientBasedCulture="true" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer dessa maneira.

```
var data = new Date("2016-10-23T20:30:01.017");
var dia = data.getDate();
var mes = data.getMonth();
var ano = data.getFullYear();

document.write(dia + '/' + mes + '/' + ano);
```

Retorno

```
23/10/2016
```

Comment: Sua solução até funciona e mostra a data formatada, mas eu estive pesquisando e preciso `tipar` essa coluna como tipo "DateTime` para fazer ordenação.

Answer (score 1):

Serialize os dados para o Datatable.net já no formato correto invés de usar javascript para formatar a data. Entregue o dado já pronto.

Nesta linha: `oCliente.DataCadastro = item.DataCadastro;`

Você deve fazer: `oCliente.DataCadastro = item.DataCadastro.ToShortDateString();`

A propriedade DataCadastro da classe Cliente deve ser uma string. Se Cliente foi um objeto de domínio, você deve criar uma view model para sua tela, no caso, ClienteViewModel e nessa view model, DataCadastro será uma string.

Comment: no método de retorno JSonResult da controller já está serealizado: {23/10/2016 20:30:01}.

Comment: Então de onde esta vindo o 2016-10-23T20:30:01.017 que você mencionou na pergunta? Além disso, se seu objeto que esta sendo serializado é tem uma propriedade DateTime, você deve retornar uma string em vez de DateTime. Ai ao construir seu objeto, você pode colocar algo como CampoDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(). Este método ToShortDateString já retorna no formato da cultura configurada na aplicação.

Comment: Ou pode fazer um DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

Comment: Essa Data vem do banco Sql Server eu editei a pergunta para melhorar o entendimento. Quando eu populo o objeto na Controller o formato está ok, porém na View carrega em outro formato, inicialmente no mRender eu pensei algo como `return ´'<td>' + dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + '</td>';` , mas não funciona e estou imaginando se não é alguma configuração no próprio `Datatable.net`